# Windows 7 and activation from MSDN?

Tags: windows-7, msdn

I have laptop which has Windows Vista and Ubuntu. I got some problem with the laptop and I  am looking for clean installation of Windows 7 Pro and I have MSDN account, I found an .iso image of Windows and I also have the product keys.

So does it that mean I can download the .iso and use the product key from my MSDN account for the installation?

Please Let me know because don't know why Windows 7 Pro is really expensive compared to Windows 8. I'd like to stay with Windows 7 since I like it a thousand times better than Windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: Just install windows with the product key

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your comment...but curious if I download the .iso and product key will it be like the retail version or it is deifferent?.. And also do I need to activate windows again and again?.

Comment: You need to activate Windows.  Your license is a full MSDN license

Answer (score 0):

Your MSDN license allows you to download in install different operating systems to develop on and test your application against. This includes all versions of Windows 7 including Pro and Home.

Windows 7 Pro is more expensive as it has more features enabled than the home version and meant to be used by developers.

You just need to download the .iso and use the product activation keys that come with your MSDN license.

Comment: so in future if my msdn subcription expires will my installed windows 7 be genuine forever?

Comment: @MrA as long as you don't try to use the same  product key more than once it will remain genuine.